# Express $a_n$ with: $a_1, a_2, a_3, n.$

Tags: sequences-and-series

$a_{n+3} - 3a_{n+2} + 3a_{n+1} - a_n = 1.$
Express $a_n$ with: $a_1, a_2, a_3, n.$

**Hint:**
Create a new series that's defined like this:
$x_n = a_{n+2} - a_{n+1}.$

**What I have discovered so far:**
$$x_n = (n-1)(d + \tfrac{n-2}2)$$ where $d$ is $$x_2 - x_1 = 
a_3 - 2a_2 - a_1 +1\\\implies  x_n=(n−1)(a_3 - 2a_2 - a_1 +1+\tfrac{n−2}2).$$

Comment: Please use MathJax  https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: Plz also provide the context of the problem, the work you did and where you got stuck.

Comment: You were given a hint...what happens when you try to follow it?

Comment: Have you tried the hint? What happened?

Comment: Your first equation simplifies to $5=0$.

Comment: I guess is $a_{n+3}-3a_{n+2}+3a_{n+1}-a_{n}=1$ and the hint should be $x_n=a_{n+2}-a_{n+1}$? In that way you would get $x_{n+1}-2x_{n}+x_{n-1}=1$.

Comment: @JulianMejia  I'm guessing that $x_n=a_{n+2}-a_n+1$

Comment: @lulu what about the statement of the problem, do you think the OP meant to write what I wrote?

Comment: @JulianMejia  I mean, I expect that what I wrote is the intended hint.

Comment: You do not need advanced material to solve the question. The question appears under the heading "Induction and Series". However, the question should be a bit difficult. As for the hint...                
I discovered that: 
x_n+2 - 2x_n+1 + x_n = 1.        
so:
x_n = (n-1)(d + (n-2) / 2) where d is x_2 - x_1 = 
a_3 - 2a_2 - a_1 +1 Sorry for the mess... I'm new here and my English is not the best ...

Comment: It is $$a_n=c_3 n^2+c_2 n+c_1+\frac{1}{6} \left(n^3-3 n^2+2 n\right)$$

Comment: Could not W|A  help you for solve the equation ?

Comment: @Dr. Sonnhard Graubner
explanation??? Have you used complex material (eg integrals and such)/ a calculator? And do you mean $a_1, a_2, a_3$ instead of $c_1, c_2, c_3$?

Comment: $a_n$ is linear, so use the ansatz $$a_n=q^n$$ and for the particular solution make the ansatz $$An^3+Bn^2+Cn+D$$

Answer (score 0):

Use the hint:

$1 = a_{n+3} - a_n - 3(a_{n+2} - a_{n+1}) = (a_{n+3} - a_{n+2}) + (a_{n+2} - a_{n+1}) + (a_{n+1} - a_n) - 3(a_{n+2} - a_{n+1}) = x_{n+1} + x_n + x_{n-1} - 3x_n$

That should give you a fair start on how to do the rest :)

edit: ${a_n+1}$ $=>$ $a_{n+1}$

Comment: I still don't understand what's going on? Can you direct me a little more?